# How to show Heads-Up notification in React Native using RNFirebase when background mode?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I get a problem to show Heads-up notification in react native using rnfirebase (https://rnfirebase.io) when background mode/app is not open, I try to look for many examples but fail all, this is my script :

bgMessaging.js

```
// @flow
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// Optional flow type
import type, { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase';

export default async (RemoteMessage) => {
    // handle your message

    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import bgMessaging from './apps/components/bgMessaging';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging);
```

Please anyone help me to create Heads-up notification when background mode, because I very need it.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to set `priority` in options when sending push from backend. It is not something that can be done from app side when it comes to the background mode.